Reporting devexpreess Blazor server app System.InvalidOperationException: Document is creating
I'm trying to populate a report with data entering value to the parameters but when I submit the value it gives me this error in the output:
System.InvalidOperationException: Document is creating.
   at DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.DevExpress.XtraReports.IReport.CreateDocumentCoreAsync(Single progressRange, CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.DocumentCreator.CreateAsync(Single progressRange, CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Reporting.Viewer.Internal.Services.ReportBuilderWasm.BuildAsync(IReport report, CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Reporting.DxReportViewer.StartBuildAsync()
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Reporting.DxReportViewer.OnSubmitParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters, ParametersRequestEventArgs args)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteSynchronously(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__23_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteBackground(WorkItem item)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost: Error: Unhandled exception in circuit 'tOr_FbeTz-ViixOj0F5pGHH79L3Rmg508c5YcnBrIck'.

I'm using dotnet core and blazor server app. How can I resolve this problem?
